# How do I use Ninject with ActionResults while making the controller IoC-framework-agnostic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, actionresult

Nearly all of the Ninject examples I've seen explain how to use it with ASP.NET MVC, which will automatically inject dependencies into controllers. How would I use Ninject manually though? Let's say I have a custom ActionResult:

```
public class JsonResult : ActionResult
{
    [Inject] public ISerializer Serializer { get; set; }

    public JsonResult(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        // do something here
    }

    // more code that uses Serializer
}
```

Then in my controller, I'm using `JsonResult` in a method like this:

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var someObject = repo.GetObject(id);
    return new JsonResult(someObject);
}
```

As you can see, I'm instantiating the object myself, which sidesteps Ninject's injection, and `Serializer` will be null. However, doing it the following way doesn't seem quite right to me:

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var someObject = repo.GetObject(id);
    return IoC.Kernel.Get<JsonResult>(someObject);
}
```

Because now there's not only a dependency on Ninject in the controller, but I also have to expose the Ninject kernel in a static class/singleton and ensure that objects that rely on injection are only created via kernel.

Is there a way to somehow configure Ninject to inject the dependency without relying on exposing the kernel? I'd like to be able to use the `new` keyword if at all possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a factory that gets the kernel injected: E.g.

```
public class ResultFactory : IResultFactory
{
    public ResultFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public JsonResult CreateJsonResult(object obj)
    {
        var result = this.kernel.Get<JsonResult>();
        result.ObjectToSerialize = obj;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Inject this factory into the controller and use it to create your action results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should turn your `JsonResult` inside out:

```
public class JsonResult : ActionResult
{
    public ISerializer Serializer { get; private set; }

    public object ObjectToSerialize { get; set; }

    public JsonResult(ISerializer serializer)
    {
        this.Serializer = serializer;
    }

    // more code that uses Serializer
}
```

This way you can retrieve the `JsonResult` with the container like this:

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var result = IoC.Kernel.Get<JsonResult>();

    result.ObjectToSerialize = repo.GetObject(id);

    return result;
}
```

Changing the signature of the `JsonResult` also enables Ninject to create an instance automatically. Because of this you can let Ninject automatically inject it as dependency into your controller:

```
public MyController(JsonResult result)
{
    this.result = result;
}

public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    this.result.ObjectToSerialize = repo.GetObject(id);

    return this.result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem any different than what I had. It just reverses the `IoC.Kernel.Get<>` with the `ObjectToSerialize`. I'd like to optimally be able to remove the `IoC.Kernel.Get<>` call completely.

Comment: When you want to remove the `IoC.Kernel.Get<>` calls, you should let Ninject inject your dependencies in the controller's constructor. By changing the `JsonResult` the way I showed, allows you to do automatic constructor injection. Look at my updated example.