# Ninject Get Instance from Kernel

Tags: ninject-2

I am new to Ninject and I am new to stackoverflow too.

I am using it with the ninject.web.mvc extension, I was able to initialize it correctly like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication 
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(AssemblyLocator.GetBinFolderAssemblies());
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

And here is my class assemlylocator that scans all the assemblies in the bin folder, searching for all the Ninject modules in the assembly.

```
public static class AssemblyLocator
{ 
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection AllAssemblies = null; 
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection BinFolderAssemblies = null;

    static AssemblyLocator() 
    { 
        AllAssemblies = new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly>( 
            BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList()); 

        IList<Assembly> binFolderAssemblies = new List<Assembly>(); 

        string binFolder = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "bin\\"; 
        IList<string> dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(binFolder, "*.dll", 

        SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList(); 

        foreach (string dllFile in dllFiles) 
        { 
            AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile); 
            Assembly locatedAssembly = AllAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => 
            AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(a.GetName(), assemblyName)); 

            if (locatedAssembly != null) 
            { 
                binFolderAssemblies.Add(locatedAssembly); 
            } 
        }

        BinFolderAssemblies = new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> (binFolderAssemblies); 
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies() 
    { 
        return AllAssemblies; 
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> GetBinFolderAssemblies() 
    { 
        return BinFolderAssemblies; 
    } 
}
```

Everything works fine in my controller:

```
public class ReteController : Controller 
{ // // GET: /Rete/ 

    private readonly IReteService _service;

    public ReteController(IReteService _service)
    {
        if (_service == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IReteService");
        }
        this._service = _service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_service.getReti());
    }
```

Until here almost everything was easy to learn, now my problem is that if I need to create a new instance of an object that was bind in the NinjectModule From Ninject I don't know how to acces the kernel from heare.

```
//this is jus a ex.

public ActionResult NewRete() { 
    IRete xItem = Kernel.get();
    xItem.name= "hope";
    return View(xItem);
}
```

the problem is that i am not able to find the kernel from my controller. I need to inject it too in the constructor??

I hope somebody can help me. Thank a lot for the big help that you guys give me all the days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I use Ninject with ActionResults while making the controller IoC-framework-agnostic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083352/how-do-i-use-ninject-with-actionresults-while-making-the-controller-ioc-framework/4087053#4087053)

It's basically the same for you. Create a factory aand inject it to your controller.

Comment: Hello Remo. I met this fantastic post from Mark Seemann, http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/30/DontCallTheContainerItllCallYou.aspx